# Tag synonym for stackoverflow: qtp ==> quicktest-pro

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[QuickTest Professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional) has two tags in stackoverflow. [qtp](/questions/tagged/qtp) (which currently has 232 questions) and [quicktest-pro](/questions/tagged/quicktest-pro) (22 questions all of which are also tagged QTP).

I've created a [synonym suggestion months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qtp/synonyms) but this is a relatively obscure tag and I need **2 more** votes to make the synonym stick.

---

**Edit:** I changed the tag from [support](/questions/tagged/support) to [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), since it seems that questions tagged support aren't on anybodies queue.

Comment: I thought qtp was for [Q-tips](http://www.qtips.com/)...

Answer (score 4):

After over a month of waiting for something to happen I manually re-tagged all relevant questions. If any of the stackexchange team sees this, I think the synonym process is badly flawed.

Comment: I'd vote on the synonym but I don't have the rep in the tag :) It might be because I avoid having to use QTP.